# How to migrate only the updated data from sql server to postgres? and not the whole data again

Tags: python, sql-server, postgresql, database-migration

I have already done the data migration from SQL Server to Postgres. Here I am able to compare the row difference between both the tables in different databases. I have added a new row to the SQL Server table now I want only that new row to be updated in the Postgres table and not the whole table.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def ask_mssql():
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@' + 'RONY' + '/' + 'testdb' + '?driver=SQL+Server')
    return engine


def ask_postgre():
    db_string = "postgres+psycopg2://{}:{}@{}/{}".format('postgres', 'rony1234',
                                                     '127.0.0.1',
                                                     'mockdb')
    engine = create_engine(db_string)
    return engine


def mssql_syntax(diff, tablename, order):
    query = 'select top {} * from {} order by {} desc'.format(diff, tablename, order)
    return query

def postgre_syntax(diff, tablename, order):
    query = 'select * from {} order by {} desc limit {}'.format(tablename, order, diff)
    return query

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db_type = input("Please enter client's db: mssql, postgresql, oracle\n")
    db_type = db_type.lower()
    if db_type == 'mssql':
        engine_client = ask_mssql()

    db_type_our = input("Please enter your db: mssql, postgresql, oracle\n")
    db_type_our = db_type_our.lower()
    if db_type_our == 'postgresql':
        engine_our = ask_postgre()

    table_name = input('\nInput the client table:\n')
    query = 'select count(*) from {}'.format(table_name)
    df_client = pd.read_sql(query,engine_client)

    our_table = input('\nInput the table name in your db\n')
    pquery = 'select count(*) from {}'.format(our_table)
    df_our = pd.read_sql(pquery,engine_our)

    if df_client.values[0][0] != df_our.values[0][0]:
        diff = df_client.values[0][0] - df_our.values[0][0]
        print('\nDifference of {} rows found'.format(diff))
        order_column = input('\nPlease enter a column to order the data on\n')

        if db_type == 'mssql':
            query = mssql_syntax(diff, table_name, order_column)

        if db_type == 'postgresql':
            query = postgre_syntax(diff, table_name, order_column)

            df = pd.read_sql(query, engine_client)

            df.to_sql(our_table, engine_our, if_exists='append')

        else:
            print('\nTable already Updated.')
```

Comment: can you help? @Mike Organek

Comment: ETL is complicated. You're in WAY over your head and have only just begun to scratch the surface of the complications you need to address. No one can give you specific, useful suggestions without knowing anything about the DDL of the source tables and what changes over time. In simple terms, you need a way to know that a row has changed (or has been added or has been deleted) after a certain point in time. If you don't have that information, then you have no choice but to refresh everything.

Comment: And you haven't mentioned in the target table (postgres) can be changed. That significantly increases the level of complicated logic you will need.

Comment: @SMor Its already in the code it shows the difference between rows. What i want in addition is that only that particular row which has been added only that row gets updated. I can do the whole table again but its time consuming